# How do I install 1.5.4 version of Nokogiri with extra configurations?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, nokogiri

I am trying to install Nokogiri version 1.5.4 as the Ruby version I am required to use is 1.8.7.

I have been following the instructions for Mac OS at: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

It requires me to pass additional configs to make it work but I end up getting the message:

```
Error installing nokogiri:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

Here is how my command looks:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/liba -v '1.5.4'
```

I am not sure if I am passing the specific version to be installed correctly.

Can anyone please tell me how to pass the version to be installed along with all the other configs that I need to pass?

Comment: Try setting the paths up to the `include` directory not further. Weird, I'm using MacPorts and rarely (only once iirc) had any issues with paths.

Comment: @atmosx i am using brew.. maybe that is the culprit.. trying with port now.